# Easiest way to use relative URLs in my WordPress header

Tags: headers

What is the easiest way please to use relative URLs in my WordPress header for calling all JS and CSS files?

So instead of:

```
<script src="https://xn--bsta-bredband-bfb.se/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.3.2" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
```

I want:

```
<script src="/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.3.2" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you need to? They're generated automatically, so it doesn't save you any work?

Comment: Why don't you use the `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` to generate thoses links? You can refer to this page for the documentation. You should not place "relative" links since if you have to move the WordPress files away, it could break everything if you manually enter relatives paths. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/